# Simple and popular javascript framework for chrome ext. development

Tags: javascript, frameworks, backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, knockout.js

I'm looking for a simple Javascript framework for my Chrome extension development.
I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI, but as my project grows, my orientation in the code is worse. So I need some kind of consistent MV* framework that is really simple&lightweight, popular (because of help and tutorials) and that could be used with jQuery and jQuery UI (or the framework could contain anything similar). Any ideas? Don't suggest me TodoMVC - I tried it and every implementation except jQuery is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For structuring your javascript application, I suggest using Backbonejs. It's lightweight, and it even uses jQuery, so you should feel quite at home. Assuming you need richer widget than what is built into the browser, instead of using jQueryUI you may want to look into "Twitter Bootstrap", which is quite pleasant to work with, looks great and already supports responsive applications (which may or may not be necessary for your Chrome Extensions). I also believe it is a lot more lightweight than jQueryUI, but I really haven't looked into that in detail on my own. The same combo also works great for traditional web pages, web apps, single page applications and even works quite well on mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you, Twitter bootstrap looks great :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question with Knockout.js - have you found any compelling reasons not to go with that? I've been using it extensively in conjunction with jQuery and jQuery UI, it plays nicely and has plenty of clean extension points. There is a big support community on here and elsewhere, and the documentation is excellent. I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Yes, Knockout looks great. I'm choosing between Knockout, Backbone and Angular right now.

Comment: Knockout doesn't actually work with Chrome extensions because of Chrome's content security policy. See here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/o9PU4gjY2XY/PMFooa_PPUoJ

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is the winner. I found the best resources.